# Convert this SELECT statement into update correctly

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need this sql to update every row with duplicate names with values that are name(autoincremented number). For instance for three rows with the name like:

```
name
name
name
```

I need them to be updated into:

```
name(1)
name(2)
name(3)
```

instead.

I managed to succesfully create a SELECT statement that does just that. I am really struggling however with converting it into an actual UPDATE. Please help.

My SQL:

```
    SELECT id,name
      ,CASE WHEN (count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name)) > 1 THEN
          regexp_replace(name, '(.*)',
          '\1('
          || row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id)
          || ')'
          )
       ELSE name END AS name
FROM   public.table
ORDER BY public.table.name;
```

I am using Postgres btw.

Posting working solution here:

```
WITH c as (
   SELECT id,name AS y
      ,CASE WHEN (count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name)) > 1 THEN
          regexp_replace(name, '(.*)',
          '\1('
          || row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id)
          || ')'
          )
       ELSE name END AS name
FROM   public.table
ORDER BY public.table.name
)
UPDATE public.table AS t 
SET name = c.name 
FROM c
WHERE t.id = c.id
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `update from`:

```
with c as (
   SELECT id,name as name_o
      ,CASE WHEN (count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name)) > 1 THEN
          regexp_replace(name, '(.*)',
          '\1('
          || row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id)
          || ')'
          )
       ELSE name END AS name
FROM   public.table
ORDER BY public.table.name
)
update public.table t 
set t.name = c.name 
from c
where t.id = c.id
;
```

of course in transaction - I could not possibly check the statement

Comment: So unfortunately I get an error saying that the name in set t.name = c.name (c.name specifically) is ambiguous.

Comment: That won't work since it is a name of the column and I can't change it. I made it into an alias and now it's working. Thank you for your help.